# Calculation reasoning in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

In the book [Theorem Proving in Higher Order Logics](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ZFVqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=We%20now%20inspect%20a%20bit%20further%20how%20the%20proof%20actually%20proceeds,%20and%20recall%20that%20the%20original%20Mizar%20proof%20basically%20imitates%20a%20simplification%20process.%20The%20justifications%20of%20intermediate%20claims%20(as%20indicated%20by%20by)%20are%20only%20of%20marginal%20interest%20here.%20We%20look%20more%20closely%20at%20the%20transformational%20process%20of%20the%20equations%20involved,%20which%20is%20represented%20at%20the&source=bl&ots=TRjwlknOOK&sig=ACfU3U2sc2hLkZ2NjzUp3wjXKCbUPhNu0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-1aWrhp7jAhXGalAKHY6_DZwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20now%20inspect%20a%20bit%20further%20how%20the%20proof%20actually%20proceeds%2C%20and%20recall%20that%20the%20original%20Mizar%20proof%20basically%20imitates%20a%20simplification%20process.%20The%20justifications%20of%20intermediate%20claims%20(as%20indicated%20by%20by)%20are%20only%20of%20marginal%20interest%20here.%20We%20look%20more%20closely%20at%20the%20transformational%20process%20of%20the%20equations%20involved%2C%20which%20is%20represented%20at%20the&f=false), page 77, there is an example that shows:

[image]

The proof structure used in this example is for calculation reasoning. Then, the most recent equation right-hand side should be equal to the left-hand side of the current equation, as shown below:

[image]

Can you please explain what is going on in example 1?

Comment: Welcome! You question is rather vague. What precisely do you have a question about?